# Mean value theorem of differentiation/limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, means

$$F'(c)= 0 , a<c<b$$
$$=>0=f'(c)\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
$$=>f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)f'(c)$$

I am confused. Above sum is written in my book. But, multiplication with 0 is forever 0. I am thinking how $b-a$ moved to left. And, while $f'(c)$ had to move to denominator of LHS. But, it moved to numerator. How? I was watching a tutorial on [Mean Value theorem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SL2RobwU_M4). He wrote that

$$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

Did my book mistake?

Comment: The second line seems to be wrong. May be a typo.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy So, it should be $F'(c)=f'(c)$ $=>\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)$.. Is it the correct one?